# Finding values in a dictionary if key matches in a range

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list and a dictionary:

```
l = [1, 4, 22, 33]
dict = {1: 'red', 17: 'green', 33: 'blue'};
```

My goal is to return a new list composed by the values (colors) associated to each element in `l` if it is between `key` to `key+16`.

I know how to retrieve the value if an element of a list matches a key in the dictionary, but I don't know how to consider each key as a range and assign a color for every element in `l`.

The expected output would be:

```
['red', 'red', 'green', 'blue']
```

I know that by generating a list from the dict I would be able to iterate over the two lists, easily finding the values in a range. The problem is that I would be working with two of more than 80,000 elements per list, so the time is too much and I thought a dictionary would be better.

Comment: *but I don't know how to consider each key as a range* make a `range()` with `l[x]` and `l[x]+16` as boundaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this simply with integer division:

```
>>> l = [1, 4, 22, 33]
>>> dct = {1: 'red', 17: 'green', 33: 'blue'}  # don't name your own dictionary dict
>>> [dct[16*((x-1)//16)+1] for x in l]
['red', 'red', 'green', 'blue']
```

Basically, this maps every number from e.g. `1` to `16` inclusive to `1`, every number from `17` to `32` inclusive to `17`, etc.